# How to resolve bean dependencies conditionally in Spring using @Conditional annotation

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean which also has a dependency on another bean, both of which are annotated with the same spring conditional:

```
@Component
@Conditional(ImportEnabledCondition.class)
public class ImportEntityResource {

@Autowired
ImportService importService;
....
}
```

The importService:

```
@Component
@Conditional(ImportEnabledCondition.class)
public class ImportService{...}
```

but I always get the `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` exception.
I'd appreciate any pointers as to how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Looking at your two beans, you shouldn't get such exception 1) if the condition evaluated to true, both would have been created 2) if condition evaluated to false, neither of them would be created. So it make me think, you have wired `ImportEntityResource` and is throwing `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` and without full stack trance, unable to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Conditional is used to register bean in Spring context depending of some conditions. In your case, you can just remove it as Spring will see the dependency as ImportEntityResource has ImportService as member. If the dependency is less explicit you can use @DependsOn.